# WPF dynamic Textbox shows in different positions

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, textbox, grid

This is some interesting behavior and maybe someone could shed some light on it. I have a `Grid` that is the size of my Screen and is transparent. In that I generate a `TextBox` dynamically, but for whatever reason that `TextBox` element slides down on the screen 4 times and then reappears on top again just to do the same again.... Any ideas how I can keep that locked in one place? Btw the same happens when I use a canvas instead of loading it into the grid...

```
double x_co = Convert.ToDouble(x_coord);
double y_co = Convert.ToDouble(y_coord);
TextBox txtNumber = new TextBox();
txtNumber.Name = "L" + x_coord.ToString();
txtNumber.Height = 85;
txtNumber.Width = 200;
txtNumber.Opacity = 1;
txtNumber.FontSize = 42;
txtNumber.SetValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
txtNumber.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
txtNumber.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
txtNumber.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
txtNumber.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
txtNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
txtNumber.Margin = new Thickness(x_co, y_co, 0, 0);

RootGrid.Children.Add(txtNumber);
RootGrid.RegisterName(txtNumber.Name, txtNumber);

string tx_num = "L" + x_coord.ToString();
txtNumber= (TextBox)this.RootGrid.FindName(tx_num);
txtNumber.Text = action;
```

And thats the XAML I load it into:

```
<Window x:Name="MyPanel" x:Class="C1.hud"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="hud" Height="1080" Width="1920" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.0" Color="White"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: I would check where you are calling the above code from. Is it calling multiple times? My guess is each time you do call it, `x_coord` and `y_coord` are different, hence the sliding.

Comment: No actually the coordinates stayed the same, but i found the problem. It was the Window in Xaml that was sliding as i didnt maximize it...

WindowState="Maximized" solved the problem actually. Thank you.